# Gauss Lemma problem from do Carmo's book

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading DoCarmo's book Riemannian Geometry and in the proof of Gauss lemma at the page 69 he says that it is clear that (2) is satified for $w=w_T$. My question is why? I leave a screenshot of the lemma below. [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$|(d\exp_p)_v(v)|=|v|.$$ (This is true because the path $t\mapsto\exp_p((1+t)v)$ is a geodesic wherever defined, and the magnitude of the velocity of a geodesic is constant in time (as the Levi-Civita connection is compatible with the metric)). Now, by construction, we have $w_t=av$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Hence $$\begin{align}\langle(d\exp_p)_v(v),(d\exp_p)_v(w_t)\rangle&=a|(d\exp_p)_v(v)|^2\\&=a|v|^2\\&=\langle v,w_t\rangle.\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for filling in those details for me. I have another problem in the same section if you want to help me, i will be grateful :)